# MySQL SUM() all the values of a Column for an ID(User) & echo total

Tags: php, mysql

Successfully connected to my database. I have a table like,

```
stid |       date          | bf | ln | dn | meal_total
------------------------------------------------------
01   | 2015-11-27 13:12:01 | 1  | 2  | 3  |    6
01   | 2015-11-27 11:12:01 | 0  | 3  | 2  |    5
02   | 2015-11-27 12:12:01 | 1  | 1  | 1  |    3
03   | 2015-11-27 11:12:01 | 1  | 1  | 1  |    3
```

I just need to `echo` the `SUM` of all the values of the `meal_total` column recorded in `current month` for a `stid` like,

```
Total Meal for `stid` in current month : 11.
```

I am trying this code like,

```
 $sql = "select sum(meal_total) 
         from meal 
         where stid='$_SESSION[stid]'  
           AND date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -DAY(CURDATE())+1 DAY) ";
```

And I am trying to show the result in a html table like,

```
<? php 
echo sum(meal_total); 
?>
```

Now, Sir, please help me to solve. Thanks in advance.

[I have tried my best to clarify my problem.]

Comment: You still haven't explained what problem you're having that you need help with. What result did that code give you?

Comment: Are you executing the sql statement and saving the results somehow?  Post that part of your code.

Comment: @Sherif Sir, the code give me a blank space!

Comment: you probably need an alias `select sum(meal_total) as sum_meal_total ...` and echo `sum_meal_total`

Comment: @jeffcarey : Sir, I am trying like, 

`$queryresult = mysqli_query($dbconnection,$sql);
$sqlfetch = mysqli_fetch_array($queryresult);`

Comment: @fthiella : Yes Sir, My problem is solved! Thanks a lot to you all. I am now using this code :

`echo $sqlfetch[sum_meal_total];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any valid PHP code, I'm just going to guess that you don't know how to access the `SUM` field from the result set.

When you `SELECT SUM(meal_total)` you should alias the field in order to access it from your PHP result array like so `SELECT SUM(meal_total) AS meal_sum` and you can `echo $resultArray['meal_sum']` to get the value in question.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. If you feel the answer was helpful you should upvote it for the next person that comes along with the same problem might also find it useful.

Comment: Sir, I have no much reputation to upvote now. But When my reputation will be sufficient I will come back here again to upvote it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Group by statement in your query:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Huh? Why does he need a `GROUP BY` here?

Answer (score 0):

If you name your result, you can get it from your results a bit easier.
I suggest that you use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), which lets you easily compare parts of dates.

```
$sql = "select sum(meal_total) AS meals 
        from meal 
        where stid='$_SESSION[stid]' 
          AND DATE_FORMAT( `date`, '%Y-%m' ) = DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y-%m' )";

# get result from sql
...
#

echo $result['meals'];
```

Offtopic:
Even though I am a 'Sir', please beware that there are many (great) female programmers aswel.

Comment: Thanks sir the problem is solved now! I am using your code. It worked for me.

Comment: @RiggsFolly : Unfortunately I can't accept more than one answer here!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select
  m.stdid,
  sum(m.meal_total) as month_meals
from 
  meal as m
where 
   year(m.date)= year(month(CURRENT_DATE()) 
AND 
   month(m.date) = month(month(CURRENT_DATE())
group by m.stdid
```